# Why can't I copy IPA symbols from PDF in Linux?

Tags: ipa, transcription

I have a PDF file with some phonetic symbols (IPA) like this: ʤ, ə, etc.
If I copy a text with that symbols, I paste the text without them.

Linux mint 17.

Comment: you can use pdf extractor

Comment: What is a PDF extractor?

Comment: pdf extractor - it's converter pdf to text

Comment: Can you give me a link? I don't see it in google

Comment: you can try first and others https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr&ei=ss7uV5WIBIeMsAGg-4jQCQ&fg=1#q=online+pdf+to+text+converter

Comment: have you used them? no one doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use [apache tika](https://tika.apache.org/). After installation use this example command:

```
java -jar tika-app-1.0.jar ‐‐text < document.pdf > document.txt
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ‐‐text
 at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:593)
 at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490)
 at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439)
 at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.process(TikaCLI.java:472)
 at org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI.main(TikaCLI.java:145)

Comment: Is there a way to copy a text without converting pdf to txt?

Comment: Online pdf to txt converter :)